# Python - Random Questions Keep Repeating

Tags: python

I want my questions to be random all the time, however they keep repeating. Along with that, the if statement which corrects the user if the answer is incorrect, will still correct the user if it is correct.

```
FirstNo=random.randint(1,12)
SecondNo=random.randint(1,12)
ops=[['+', operator.add], ['-', operator.sub], ['*', operator.mul]]
op=random.choice(ops)

for i in range(1,11):
    print('Question '+str(i))
    pupilAns=input('What is '+str(FirstNo)+str(op[0])+str(SecondNo)+'? ')
    realAns=op[1](FirstNo, SecondNo)
    if pupilAns==realAns:
        score=score+1
        print('Well Done '+FN+'!')
    else:
        print("Wrong Answer "+FN+'. It was '+str(realAns))
```

Here is the full code

```
import random
import operator
score=0 #Score for Quiz

FN=input(str('What is your First Name:'))
while FN=='':
     FN=input(str('Please enter your First Name:'))
     DigitFound=True
     while DigitFound==True:
         FN=input(str('Please enter your First Name:'))
         for digit in FN:
             if digit.isdigit():
                 DigitFound=True
                 break
             else:
                 DigitFound=False

LN=input(str('What is your Last Name:'))
while LN=='':
    LN=input(str('Please enter your Last Name:'))
    DigitFound=True
    while DigitFound==True:
         LN=input(str('Please enter your Last Name:'))
         for digit in LN:
             if digit.isdigit():
                 DigitFound=True
                 break
             else:
                 DigitFound=False

Status=False
CN=input('What is your Class Name? Class 1, Class 2, or Class 3:')
while Status==False:
    if CN=='Class 1' or CN=='Class 2' or CN=='Class 3':
        Status=True #Break out of the loop and continue to the quiz
    else:
        CN=input('What is your Class Name? Class 1, Class 2, Class 3:')

FirstNo=random.randint(1,12)
SecondNo=random.randint(1,12)
ops=[['+', operator.add], ['-', operator.sub], ['*', operator.mul]]
op=random.choice(ops)

for i in range(1,11):
    print('Question '+str(i))
    pupilAns=input('What is '+str(FirstNo)+str(op[0])+str(SecondNo)+'? ')
    realAns=op[1](FirstNo, SecondNo)
    if pupilAns==realAns:
        score=score+1
        print('Well Done '+FN+'!')
    else:
        print("Wrong Answer "+FN+'. It was '+str(realAns))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid your questions from repeating, you should put your `random.randint` and `random.choice` calls in the `for`- loop. Functions in Python (and every other language afaik) are evaluated on call, so the variables `FirstNo`, `SecondNo` and `op` are all filled with the value that their respective functions returned.

Then, on each iteration in the `for`-loop, the values are never changed. So they stay the same.

Answer (score 2):

You need to select the random numbers inside your loop.  All you are doing is selecting random numbers once and then asking the question 10 times.

Answer (score 1):

Others have answered why the question isn't random, so I won't address that part of your question.

You are getting `"Wrong Answer "...` printed even when the user gives the correct answer because you are comparing a string with a number: `pupilAns` is a string, but `realAns` is an integer. So you need to either convert `pupilAns` to an `int`, or convert `realAns` to a `str` before you do the `if pupilAns==realAns:` test. I'd probably do the former, and print an error message if `pupilAns` can't be converted to an `int`.